# multilevel menu with active class

Tags: jquery, html

```html
  <div id="list">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product Category1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Category2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Category3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Category4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Category5
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Product subcategory1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Product subcategory2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Product subcategory3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Product subcategory4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Product subcategory5
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub sub category1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub sub category2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub sub category3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub sub category4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </a></li>
            </ul>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
```

Product Category5 > Product subcategory5 > Sub sub category4

if "Sub sub category4" is click page loaded whole link should get active class.

like
Product Category5(this should have active class) > Product subcategory5(this should have active class) > Sub sub category4(this should have active class)

just use of jquery or referer feature.

Comment: means ul li should get active class.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have no idea what to do means how can we identify on which category we are need a help.

Comment: You need to share the HTML, in order for everyone to understand the structure, the IDs / Classes you are using, etc. Without seeing the code and what efforts you have put in, its difficult / impossible to come up with an answer. I would rather recommend you to Google it.

Comment: click on any li each its parent li should get active class while click page should being get reload so we have to think like after reload javascript or jquery code will run again.

Answer (score 1):

So, did a search on stackOverflow, used the code to find multi-level parent, and that seems to do the trick. Check the below snippet:

```js
$.fn.nthParent = function(n) {
  var p = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p.parents('li').first().find('a').first().addClass('active')
    p = p.parents('li').first();
  }
  return p;
}

$('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nthParent(4);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Product Category1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Category2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Category3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Category4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Category5</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product subcategory1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product subcategory2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product subcategory3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product subcategory4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product subcategory5</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub category1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub category2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub category3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub sub category4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Well thank you Milan Chheda for efforts issue solved with another trick.